# How to paste multiline text to WPF RichTextBox as single paragraph?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, newline, paragraph

Assume I want to add to RichTextBox this text:

```
Text line 1
Text line 2
Text line 3
```

When `Paste()` to RichTextBox, it change `\n` to Paragraph break, but I want to keep `\n` as Line break. How I can do that? Thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep `\r`, remove `\n`:

```
rtb.Selection.Text = Clipboard.GetText().Replace("\n", "");
```